# ROS2 why the serialized message have additional bytes at the beginning

Tags: ros2, serialization

I'm experimenting with writing a ROS2 std_msgs/msg/String message to an MCAP file on iPhone. This is a simple test, I'd like to move to more complex messages later. However, I'm no expert on serialization so my question might seem dumb.

I use the CDR encoding as required by the [MCAP document](https://mcap.dev/spec/registry#cdr). The result is an array of bytes in the format of <4-byte length><utf-8 bytes>. However, I find that the ROS2 default serializer gives me an array of bytes in the format of **<leading 4 bytes>**<4-byte length><utf-8 bytes>. For example, if I encode the string "Hello, world! 0", using the [CDRCodable Swift package](https://github.com/DimaRU/CDRCodable), the hex code looks like

10000000 48656C6C 6F2C2077 6F726C64 21203000

But for the same string, ROS2 gives (generated by `serialize_message` of the `rclpy.serialization` python package)

**00010000** 10000000 48656C6C 6F2C2077 6F726C64 21203000

Without this <leading 4 bytes>, the MCAP file I created cannot be visualized by foxglove. So I figured that they are the correct encoded bytes. What is the <leading 4 bytes> here and how can I correctly produce the same bytes?

Thank you!